# 2 questions on Backbone.js MVC

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am starting to use BB.js and I am new to MVC.

1. So I use JQuery with BB and BB does not seem to be able to handle all events. Ex: The load event and I think the keboard events too. I though that when using BB, all the code would need to be in a BB Obect (ex: View Object), but now it seems like I also have to use JQuery for some events, that would kind of seperate my code in multiple parts.
2. Where do I instantiate the View (the controller)? In the controller file or in a script tag in the HTML file? What is the clean way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Backbone models/views/collections are all built to mimic jQuery and underscore APIs. So to answer your questions:

1 - Any event that can be bound to an element can be used in Backbone views. Event data is sent via a parameter to the function. ex ([via Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)):

```
var DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "dblclick"                : "open",
    "click .icon.doc"         : "select",
    "contextmenu .icon.doc"   : "showMenu",
    "click .show_notes"       : "toggleNotes",
    "click .title .lock"      : "editAccessLevel",
    "mouseover .title .date"  : "showTooltip"
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
  },

  open: function() {
    window.open(this.model.get("viewer_url"));
  },

  select: function() {
    this.model.set({selected: true});
  },

  ...

});
```

2 - You instantiate your view in your script files or in a script tag. from example above:

```
var Document = new DocumentView();

Document.render();
```